# GitLab with Docker Swarm + initial root password: can't log in

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm getting the following error when trying to login using `root` and the initial password set using the [Install GitLab using Docker swarm mode](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#install-gitlab-using-docker-swarm-mode) method.  Any suggestions how how to resolve this?  The error is a `401 Unauthorized`, but as you can see below the `root` does get created with the supplied password file.

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==,
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.0.2 at 2021-02-13 02:27:11 +0000,
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML,
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"login"=>"root", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}},
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 202ms (ActiveRecord: 32.0ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms | Allocations: 42688),
,
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log <==,
{"method":"POST","path":"/users/sign_in","format":"html","controller":"SessionsController","action":"create","status":0,"time":"2021-02-13T02:27:11.355Z","params":[{"key":"utf8","value":"✓"},{"key":"authenticity_token","value":"[FILTERED]"},{"key":"user","value":{"login":"root","password":"[FILTERED]","remember_me":"1"}}],"remote_ip":"10.0.0.2","user_id":null,"username":null,"ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36","correlation_id":"01EYCKD94QJ7K2FV14BE28WF58","meta.caller_id":"SessionsController#create","meta.remote_ip":"10.0.0.2","meta.feature_category":"authentication_and_authorization","redis_calls":8,"redis_duration_s":0.003663,"redis_read_bytes":1441,"redis_write_bytes":552,"redis_cache_calls":7,"redis_cache_duration_s":0.002813,"redis_cache_read_bytes":1337,"redis_cache_write_bytes":382,"redis_shared_state_calls":1,"redis_shared_state_duration_s":0.00085,"redis_shared_state_read_bytes":104,"redis_shared_state_write_bytes":170,"db_count":12,"db_write_count":2,"db_cached_count":1,"queue_duration_s":0.019457,"cpu_s":0.19,"db_duration_s":0.03197,"view_duration_s":0.0,"duration_s":0.20219},
,
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==,
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML,
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"login"=>"root", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}},
,
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/application.log <==,
2021-02-13T02:27:11.449Z: Failed Login: username=root ip=10.0.0.2,
,
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/application_json.log <==,
{"severity":"INFO","time":"2021-02-13T02:27:11.450Z","correlation_id":"01EYCKD94QJ7K2FV14BE28WF58","message":"Failed Login: username=root ip=10.0.0.2"},
,
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==,
Completed 200 OK in 91ms (Views: 22.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms | Allocations: 12783),
,
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log <==,
{"method":"POST","path":"/users/sign_in","format":"html","controller":"SessionsController","action":"new","status":200,"time":"2021-02-13T02:27:11.451Z","params":[{"key":"utf8","value":"✓"},{"key":"authenticity_token","value":"[FILTERED]"},{"key":"user","value":{"login":"root","password":"[FILTERED]","remember_me":"1"}}],"remote_ip":"10.0.0.2","user_id":null,"username":null,"ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36","correlation_id":"01EYCKD94QJ7K2FV14BE28WF58","meta.caller_id":"SessionsController#new","meta.remote_ip":"10.0.0.2","meta.feature_category":"authentication_and_authorization","redis_calls":11,"redis_duration_s":0.004477,"redis_read_bytes":1679,"redis_write_bytes":826,"redis_cache_calls":10,"redis_cache_duration_s":0.003627,"redis_cache_read_bytes":1573,"redis_cache_write_bytes":535,"redis_shared_state_calls":1,"redis_shared_state_duration_s":0.00085,"redis_shared_state_read_bytes":106,"redis_shared_state_write_bytes":291,"db_count":18,"db_write_count":2,"db_cached_count":3,"queue_duration_s":0.019457,"cpu_s":0.29,"db_duration_s":0.00281,"view_duration_s":0.02265,"duration_s":0.09165},
,
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==,
{"content_type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","correlation_id":"01EYCKD94QJ7K2FV14BE28WF58","duration_ms":326,"host":"192.168.1.225:8778","level":"info","method":"POST","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.1","referrer":"http://192.168.1.225:8778/users/sign_in","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:0","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","route":"","status":200,"system":"http","time":"2021-02-13T02:27:11Z","ttfb_ms":326,"uri":"/users/sign_in","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36","written_bytes":54237},
,
==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==,
10.0.0.2 - - [13/Feb/2021:02:27:11 +0000] "POST /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 200 14901 "http://192.168.1.225:8778/users/sign_in" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" 3.64
```

The root user does get created:

```
  * runit_service[gitlab-kas] action disable,
    * ruby_block[disable gitlab-kas] action run (skipped due to only_if),
     (up to date),
Recipe: gitlab::database_migrations,
  * bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] action run,
    [execute] psql:/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/structure.sql:9: NOTICE:  extension "btree_gist" already exists, skipping,
              psql:/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/structure.sql:11: NOTICE:  extension "pg_trgm" already exists, skipping,
              WARNING: Active Record does not support composite primary key.,
              ,
              user_interacted_projects has composite primary key. Composite primary key is ignored.,
              WARNING: Active Record does not support composite primary key.,
              ,
              project_authorizations has composite primary key. Composite primary key is ignored.,
              ,
              == Seed from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/fixtures/production/001_application_settings.rb,
              Creating the default ApplicationSetting record.,
              ,
              == Seed from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/fixtures/production/002_admin.rb,
              Administrator account created:,
              ,
              login:    root,
              password: password1234,
              ,
              ,
              == Seed from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/fixtures/production/010_settings.rb,
              Saved CI JWT signing key,
              ,
              == Seed from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/fixtures/production/998_gitlab_instance_administration_project.rb,
              /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/validate_url-1.0.8/lib/validate_url.rb:23: warning: URI.escape is obsolete,
              Successfully created self monitoring project.,
              ,
              == Seed from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/fixtures/production/999_common_metrics.rb,
    - execute "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20210213-32-1kam03j",
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:13.8.3-ce.0
    depends_on:
      - smtpserver
    ports:
      - "8778:8778"
      - "8722:22"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: gitlab_data
        target: /var/opt/gitlab
      - type: volume
        source: gitlab_log
        target: /var/log/gitlab
      - type: volume
        source: gitlab_config
        target: /etc/gitlab
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: "from_file('/omnibus_config.rb')"
    configs:
      - source: gitlab
        target: /omnibus_config.rb
    secrets:
      - gitlab_root_password
    networks:
      - dev_net

  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v13.8.0
    depends_on:
      - gitlab
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: gitlab_runner_config
        target: /etc/gitlab-runner
      - type: bind
        source: /var/run/docker.sock
        target: /var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - dev_net

  smtpserver:
    image: devture/exim-relay:4.93-r1
    user: 100:101
    restart: always
    hostname: ...
    environment:
      - SMARTHOST=...
      - SMTP_USERNAME=...
      - SMTP_PASSWORD=...
    networks:
      - dev_net

volumes:
  gitlab_data:
  gitlab_log:
  gitlab_config:
  gitlab_runner_config:

networks:
  dev_net:

configs:
  gitlab:
    file: ./gitlab.rb

secrets:
  gitlab_root_password:
    file: ./root_password.txt
```

And `./gitlab.rb`:

```
external_url 'http://192.168.1.225:8778'
registry_external_url 'http://192.168.1.225:8081'
gitlab_rails['initial_root_password'] = File.read('/run/secrets/gitlab_root_password')
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'devops@mydomain'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_display_name'] = 'Git'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'devops@mydomain'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_subject_suffix'] = '[Git] '
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true 
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = 'smtpserver'
#gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = ''
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 8025
#gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 25
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = 'mydomain'
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none'
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_ssl'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_force_ssl'] = false
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 8722
gitlab_rails['time_zone'] = 'America/New_York'
nginx['client_max_body_size'] = '1g'
```

And `root_password.txt`:

```
password1234
```

Comment: I notice you also see "Active Record does not support composite primary key". Did you manage to fix that as well, so that the migrations finish?

Comment: No.  I had to create the user manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, to workaround it I had to unlock the user (it was locked because password was not working):

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/unlock_user.html

Then I reset the root password:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_user_password.html

And I was able to access the portal.

I didn't understand why this happened but at least I was able to use gitlab by following these steps.

Comment: I ended up having to do that.  There must be a problem with Gitlab's initial password for root.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a few hours of sleep until I found that a `.strip` at the end solves the problem.

Correct format:

```
gitlab_rails['initial_root_password'] = File.read('/run/secrets/gitlab_root_password').strip
```

Comment: That's a great solution and find.  Nice!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similar, but the root password provided in configuration was invalid (too short).

```
    == Seed from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/fixtures/production/002_admin.rb
    Could not create the default administrator account:

    --> Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)
```

After providing valid password in `root_password.txt` I've reset all data and swarm stack, then executed again it worked as expected.